# How to check if textbox.value is numerical?

Tags: vba, textbox

I am working on a project to create GUI for instrument control.

I created a userform with a couple of textboxes to adjust instrument settings.
Entries to these textboxes should be numerical.

Since textbox.value is stored as variant, I have written a sub to check if the entry is numerical.

- If so, cast the string onto a double type variable.
- If not, send an error-message and clear the entry.

Below is the sub I have written and how I call it in textbox change event.

- For numeric entries, code executes correctly and casts the string inside textbox.value onto a double type variable.
- For non-numeric entries, textbox.value is not changing.
  I see the error-message pop, so I know the if statement is executing.

```vb
Private Sub cast_Val(user_in As String, user_out As Double) 'Cast User Input'
    If IsNumeric(user_in) = False Then
        user_in = ""
        MsgBox ("Not Numeric")
    Else
        user_out = CDbl(user_in)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dwell_txt_AfterUpdate()
    Call cast_Val(cont_ui.dwell_txt.Value, pulse_wid)

    'Dim in_txt As String
    'in_txt = cont_ui.dwell_txt.Value
    'Call cast_Val(in_txt, pulse_wid)
    'cont_ui.dwell_txt.Value = in_txt
End Sub
```

In debugging mode I checked which step values of user_in, user_out, dwell_txt.Value and pulse_wid change.

- When numeric, both the pulse_wid and user_out change at the same step.
  Since my sub is working for numeric entries, I assumed value change in the same step is how it is supposed to work.
- For non-numeric entries, I can see the user_in value change, however dwell_txt.Value stays the same.

I was suspicious of the scope of my variables. Even though all of my code is written under userform scope and dwell_txt (my textbox's name) should be contained underneath it as well, I tried declaring all my procedures and variables as Public. This did not work as well.

I tried changing the value of dwell_txt inside the cast_Val procedure. With this method, I managed to clear, however this is not a reliable method since I have a couple other textboxes in my GUI that I have to use cast_Val procedure in a similar vein.

I tried declaring the parameters of cast_Val procedure as byVal and byRef. In both options, the value inside dwell_txt did not change.

Lastly, I assigned my dwell_txt.Value into a procedure level variable and fed that variable into cast_Val.
This method seems to be a good workaround. I included this method at the end of my change event code. See the commented section for reference.

I am still curious about why my first method did not work. Why can't I feed textbox.value inside a procedure like I have done with a regular variable?

Also on a somewhat unrelated topic, is there a way to change textbox input type to integer/double rather than a variant?

Comment: When you pass `cont_ui.dwell_txt.Value` into `cast_Val` you're passing in only a copy of the textbox value - anything you do to that copy in `cast_val` has no effect on the textbox itself.

Comment: Yeah, that seems fair. However, shouldn't it be the same for `in_txt` as well. In similar vein I am passing a variable, `cont_ui.dwell_txt.Value` in first method and `in_txt` in second method, and should only effect the copy of it a.k.a. `user_in`. However for some reason second method works and first method does not.

Comment: In VBA variables are by default passed `ByRef` (by reference) so if you alter `user_in` or `user_out` inside `cast_Val`, those changes are reflected in the variables passed in from the calling procedure.

Comment: Because I am using ByRef , the values are being edited in the original variable as well.  I have tried changing it to ByVal and it did not fix my problem, and would have probably created more problems(i.e. `usser_out` changing but not the variable passed in). This part I understand clearly now, thanks for the help. However where I am stuck is why cont_ui.dwell_txt.Value is not treated as a variable. Whatever I do, passing this value always acts like ByVal instead of ByRef. Should I always assume userform entities to act this way?

Comment: When you pass `cont_ui.dwell_txt.Value` you're passing a *copy* of the `Value` proprerty   - that's a "one way" process - that copy does not give you access to *set* the `Value` property in `cast_Val`.  If you want to change the value of the textbox inside `cast_Val` then pass in the *textbox object* instead.

Comment: Alright, now it works. Thanks a lot for all the help. I didn't know you can declare function parameters as objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the support of Tim Williams, I have managed to fix the problem. The issue lied on my declaration of the `user_in` parameter.

Earlier on I have tried *String, Int, Double and Variant* types. However, this resulted in program passing a copy of the textbox property and did not let me change the property itself inside the procedure. When I declared `user_in` as *Object* type and passed `cont_ui.dwell_txt`, I was able to change the `cont_ui.dwell_txt.Value`

Below is the working version of the code posted in the original entry.

```
Private Sub cast_Val(user_in As Object, user_out As Double) 'Cast User Input'
    If IsNumeric(user_in.Value) = False Then
        user_in.Value = CStr(user_out)
        MsgBox ("Not Numeric")
    Else
        user_out = CDbl(user_in.Value)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dwell_txt_AfterUpdate()
    Call cast_Val(cont_ui.dwell_txt, pulse_wid)
End Sub
```

Once again, thanks to Tim Williams for all the help.